# How to close All previous view controller in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I close all previous view controller in ios swift 3 or 4?

Answer (score 1):

```
 func  dismiss_all(view: UIView){
    view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> dismiss_all(view : self.view)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.